# Am I right in understanding that if my supply drops due to losing territory, this won't affect my armies until the supply card is drawn?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm getting prepared to play GoT for the first time, I just wanted to clarify this rule.

Let's say I have 2 supply, this allows me to have one 3 army, and two 2 armies.

I muster up until I'm at my supply limit.

Now the territory providing the supply gets taken from me.

Am I right in understanding that I don't need to disband units until the next Supply card comes out in the Westeros phase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct: The army limit is based on your position on the Supply track, but the Supply track is *not* automatically adjusted during any of the game phases.  You would only adjust the Supply track (and thus your armies) when the a game effect explicitly commands it (i.e. a Supply card is drawn).

From [page 8 of the official rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf) (second edition, but it plays the same as first edition in this case):

> - Though a player may gain or lose Supply icons on the game
>     board throughout one or more Action Phases, **his armies
>     are reconciled only when the Supply track is adjusted** (via a
>     “Supply” Westeros card, or other game effects).

(Note: The rules also calls out "other game effects" but off-hand I have no clue what those are, or if they're second-edition-exclusive.  From first edition, I don't recall ever needing to adjust the Supply track except from a card explicitly commanding me to.)

The "Supply Example" on that same page also calls this out more clearly (emphasis mine):

> Lannister has recently lost control of Riverrun and
>   Seagard to Greyjoy (each of which contains a single Supply
>   icon). During a later Westeros Phase, a “Supply” card is
>   revealed. Due to the loss of these areas, Lannister must now
>   adjust his actual Supply from 5 to 3.
>
> **Before the “Supply” card is drawn**, Lannister has four armies
>   of 4, 3, 2, and 2 units.

Of note, the bolded text mentions that Lannister still had four armies *before the Supply card is drawn* (despite the territories being lost before then, given that the Supply card was drawn during "a *later* Westeros Phase").

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, with one exception.  Normally supply does not adjust until the supply card is drawn (at which point you will have to disband if you are over your new supply limit).

However, if your supply is adjusted down by a game effect, such as the 2nd edition Rattleshirt's Raiders Wildlings card that causes players to temporarily lose supply, this takes effect immediately and you may have to disband from this.

The card reads:

> **Lowest Bidder:** Is reduced 2 positions on the Supply track (to no lower than 0).
>
> **Everyone Else:** Is reduced 1 position on the Supply track (to no lower than 0).
>
> ***Then reconcile armies to their new Supply limits.***